# Как в qt designer связать сигнал от кнопки со своим слотом?

Tags: c++, qt

Не могу связать сигнал со слотом. Смотри открываю в Qt QtDisigner > добавляю кнопку (Push Button)  > в файле mainwindow.h пишу: `public slots: void slSelectAllTtl();` > в файле mainwindow.cpp пишу:

```
void MainWindow::slSelectAllTtl()
{
    QList<QString> titles;
    titles << "one" << "two" << "three";
    qDebug() << "It's working";
}
```

В файле mainwindow.ui жму Edit Signals/Slots F4 > Выбираю кнопку что я раньше добавлял (левая кнопка мыши на кнопке перeтягиваю на окно) > получаю окно Configure Connection там жму в левом списке clicked, теперь по идее в правом MainWindow (QMainWindow) должен быть мой слот slSelectAllTtl() но его нет почему?

Comment: Потому что он ваш, кастомный. Такой слот надо подключать вручную, например в конструкторе вашего класса. Попробуйте, это не больно и даже приятно)

Comment: Вы немножко опоздали так и сделал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось вот так вот подключить но может это не правильно:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui->selAllPotion, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(slSelectAllTtl()));
}
```